# Accessing a Network share with different credentials

Tags: windows-10, network-shares

I am trying to access a network share in my workgroup with different credentials. The user am trying to login in has no password. So how do I log in ?

I may be miss spelling the username, if I am allowed to use a  blank password.

Comment: Try `<ipdaddress>\username` and then press `Enter` where IP address is the IP address of the machine with the account you authenticating with no password - I assume this account is defined on that machine - so it's the "different" credential you're referring to. That "different" credential also need SHARE permissions and NTFS folder level permissions as well on the SHARE so be sure to confirm that's all set as well.

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT Great!! After hours of googling around, trials and errors, reading Microsoft's bu***t, etc, I finally stumble upon your comment... You are my hero of the day! If you'd like to put that comment into an answer (valuable for Windows 10 Entreprise) I'll be so glad and happy to vote for it. Also other people may find an answer easier to read than a comment. thx again!

Comment: @toesslab.ch There you go, I added as an answer... see below. I did that a long time ago and forgot about it, I'm glad you find it helpful and suggested to add as answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `<ipdaddress>\username` and then press `Enter` where the IP address is the IP address of the machine with the account you authenticate with no password—I assume this account is defined on that machine—so it's the "different" credential you're referring to.

**Note**: The "different" credential also needs SHARE permissions and NTFS folder level permissions on the SHARE so be sure to confirm that's all set as well.

---

### Further Resources

- [How Permissions Work](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc783530(v=ws.10).aspx)
- [How IT works NTFS Permissions](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2005.11.howitworksntfs.aspx)

Comment: Always cool when things get back to life after years...

Answer (score 1):

First: run cmd (as administrator) and type `cmdkey /delete:your-Network-Share`

Second: control panel => network and sharing center => change advance sharing setting > All network > turn off password protected sharing > save changes

Last step: open your-network-share again.

Comment: not working on Windows 10 Entreprise...